# Led dimming circuit is not able to switch off the led

Tags: led-driver, dali

We are working on an LED dimmer circuit which supports DALI2.0 Interface. We already received the hardware and working on software only. LED driver circuit is based TPS92515HV and below is the circuitry

[image]

But the issue is LED is not switching off even if the control signal which is Iadj is 0. We tried shorting Iadj to GND and still, there is a current of 3.5mA through LED which makes LED on always unless power is removed. This will lead to non-complinace of DALI OFF command. The board is powered externally and we cannot control it and also we cannot afford any major component addition like relays to control power line to the driver chip. Is there anything to do with TPS92515HV configuration.??

Comment: What does the datasheet say? Far from all LED drivers can regulate down to 0 mA, save for forcing EN low.

Comment: @winny There is no EN pin on chip

Comment: @raforanz: It has a pwm pin

Comment: What's the value of VLED a) when operating at full brightness and b) when it's still putting out 3.5mA?

Comment: Why are you putting your PWM on IADJ? That should surely be going to the PWM pin? (Unless this is something about the DALI interface I don't understand): Did you look at the [typical application schematic](https://imgur.com/a/8t2R4)?

Comment: Then what the datasheet say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps92515hv.pdf) in section 8.3.11 PWM (UVLO and Enable) says

> Because
> the PWM
> pin is also UVLO
> (undervoltage
> lockout
> and device
> enable),
> when
> pulled
> low it is necessary
> to ensure
> the output
> is 100%
> OFF.
> The high-side
> FET
> driver
> has a small
> leakage
> path
> to the output.
> Although
> very
> small
> (<<100
> μ
> A), theLEDs
> could
> glow
> if the current
> was not eliminated.
> The 100-
> μ
> A (typical)
> pulldown
> is activated
> and
> held ON while
> PWM
> is low and ensures
> no light output

so disable the driver when you want to turn it off by pulling the PWM pin low from your micro.